# Newline and a colon?

Tags: ruby

I'm going through Codecademy's tutorial for Ruby, and I've been asked to do the following:

Use .each to iterate over the secret_identities hash. Use puts to print each key-value pair, separated by a colon and a space (:), to the console.

The hash was created to start, so I'm just going to skip right to the code that I put in.

```
secret_identities.each { | hero, identity | puts "{#hero}: {#idenity}" }
```

Then I get the following error:

> Oops, try again.  It looks like you aren't printing each
>   colon-separated key-value pair on its own line. Check the hint if you
>   need help!

So what exactly do I need to do to make it compliant to the code?

Comment: String interpolation is done with `"#{expr}"` not `"{#expr}"`.

Comment: thank you. The example put the very clearly. Just didn't notice it in my coding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typo? `#idenity` should be `#identity`?

Comment: well this is embarrassing... I'm going to have to take a course for late night coding

Comment: We all do it. Glad it was easy to fix.

Answer (score 2):

You misspelled **identity**.

```
#Wrong
secret_identities.each { | hero, identity | puts "{#hero}: {#idenity}" }

#Correct
secret_identities.each { | hero, identity | puts "{#hero}: {#identity}" }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got two problems here. One is a mis-matched variable and the other is the formatting:

```
secret_identities.each { |hero, identity| puts "#{hero}: #{identity}" }
```

Note that it's `#{...}` for string interpolation. Whatever's inside the brackets gets evaluated as Ruby and then stringified with `to_s` where required.